# How to configure UTF-8 for plain/text Haml template for ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, character-encoding, actionmailer, plaintext

From within my Rails 3.2 app I am sending [multipart emails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-multipart-emails) and therefore prepared a template for plain/text emails. This is the template..

`app/views/welcome_mailer/welcome_email.text.haml`:

```
Willkommen #{@user.name}!

Du hast dich erfolgreich auf unserer Webseite mit deiner 
E-Mail-Adresse #{@user.email} registriert. Damit du dich
dort anmelden kannst, bestätige bitte einmalig deine E-Mail-Adresse
mittels folgendem Link:

#{confirmation_url(@user, confirmation_token: @user.confirmation_token)}

Viel Spass auf der Webseite und einen schönen Tag.
```

The content of the welcome mail contains [German Umlauts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_umlaut). The **special characters are not displayed correctly** when I inspect the email on the receiver side. How can configure the correct character encoding for the content?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a way to fix it ?

Comment: Sorry @anthony, I do not remember. But you can have a look at [the project](https://github.com/teikei/teikei) yourself and find out. Feel free to post an answer here.

Comment: Thanks ! Actually my issue was coming from inky-rb gem (http://stackoverflow.com/a/41634312/3700317)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sth like the following in your mailer?

```
mail(charset: "utf-8", content_type: "text/html")
```