# Rails: UTF-8 encoding issue with mailer and text partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, encoding, utf-8, mailer

I am building a Rails application and am face of a problem with my text mailer: I can’t find how to make special character (é, è, à, …) to be encoded properly.
It works great with html mailer because I can set the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` but that’s not possible with text mailer.

**Example of issue in text mailer** (my_mailer.text.erb)

```
D&#233;monstration # Démonstration
```

**Extract of my mailer**:

```
mail from: <from>,
     to: <to>,
     subject: <subject>,
     body: <body>
```

I also tried to add `charset: 'utf-8'` property to the mail method without success either.
How can I fix this encoding issue ?

Thanks for your help !

**My project**:

- Rails 5.0.1
- Ruby 2.3.3
- [Inky-rb](https://github.com/zurb/inky-rb) gem (Foundation template renderer for mailers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found my issue. It was coming from the [inky-rb](https://github.com/zurb/inky-rb) gem which has some problem to understand encoding.

I just rename my layout (or template) like this:

```
# app/views/layouts  
default.text.inky # => default.text.erb
```